# Plotting moist static energy fluxes

Tags: meteorology, climatology, energy-balance

I'm trying to plot Moist static energy fluxes (vectors) and their divergence like the attached Figure. I have monthly means of u, v, temperature, specific humidity and geopotential from(1000-100 hPa) for calculating MSE, but my results are very different from the attached figure. I also want to know how to calculate the northward and eastward fluxes for plotting MSE vectors on the map. What procedure must be used to obtain these variables? Is there a special process?

[image: Atmospheric moist static energy fluxes F (vectors)]

Comment: What are your results? Are the datasets same and what are they? How have you tried to plot them?